# Timer Task always return false

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I have this code

```
ischanged = false;
    public void doTimerTaskforXML(final GeneralObject Gen_Obj) {
        XMLTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        String NewXML = "";
                        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                        NewXML = parser.getXmlFromUrl(Gen_Obj.URL);
                        if (NewXML != null && NewXML != ""
                                && NewXML.length() > 0) {
                            if (!Gen_Obj.XML.equals(NewXML)
                                    || Gen_Obj.XML.length() != NewXML.length()) {
                                ischanged = true;
                                Log.i(TAG, "XMl has been changed");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        XMLTimer.schedule(XMLTimerTask, 0, 60000);
        Log.i(TAG, "XNL not change");
    }

    public boolean IsChanged(GeneralObject Gen_Obj) {
        doTimerTaskforXML(Gen_Obj);
        Log.i(TAG, "ischanged= " + ischanged);
        return ischanged;
    }
```

which check for xml change

When I call function IsChanged and take it's return it alwayes return false

what the wrong in this code 
?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as the method IsChanged executes completely before doTimerTaskforXML's run method is called. and thats why you get default value as false. You need to use sync approach, if you want the return value immediately in the same call.

Alternatively, ( async approach) you can implement [AsyncTask class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which is best for parsing xml  in background. It has two methods doInBackground and onPostExecute. You'll have to override both of them, put your parsing in doInBackground method and when the parsing is done onPostExecute callback will be run.

Comment: But I want to work this timer at different times, for example, the first time for 5 minutes the second time for 10 minutes, and so on

Comment: How I can do that using  AsyncTask ?

Comment: @user3604882 i didn't understood your codeflow. But I assume that IsChanged method is called only once, So can you avoid returning any boolean value from this method. Instead call another method when you set isChanged = true, to take actions based on that.